# How to remove category thumbnails in woocommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to show my product only not category thumbnail how can i remove this? Please give me a solution it's important.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the customizer.
In your WordPress Admin Dashboard, navigate Themes > Customize.

Once in, navigate WooCommerce > Product Catalog.
You should change under `Shop page display`, select `Show Products` and that's it.